# Creating a cabinet using CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have found this codepen with a cabinet.

I could really use it for my site, but when I try to add two shelves, the bottom 2 shelves are outside the cabinet. When playing around with the height of the cabinet, the shelves just shrink/grow but the bottom 2 shelves remain outside the cabinet.

I tried adding borders to the bottom shelves, but that was even worse.

I tried making a cabinet with only 2 shelves but then you would get this ugly brown square at the bottom.

Why am I seeing all these issues?

```css
.cabinet {
  position: absolute;
  width: 460px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #45221c;
  top: 40px;
  left: 30%;
  border: 10px solid #69342b;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cabinet .cabinet-top {
  width: 104%;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #572b23;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: -20px;
  left: -2%;
  position: absolute;
}
.cabinet .shelf {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cabinet .shelf .back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 2%;
  width: 96%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2c1512;
  box-shadow: inset 10px 15px 15px #21100d;
}
.cabinet .shelf .base {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #331915;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
.cabinet .shelf .front {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #69342b;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cabinet">
  <div class="cabinet-top"></div>

  <div class="shelf">
    <div class="upper-left-triangle"></div>
    <div class="upper-right-triangle"></div>

    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="base"></div>
    <div class="front"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="shelf">
    <div class="upper-left-triangle"></div>
    <div class="upper-right-triangle"></div>

    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="base"></div>
    <div class="front"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="shelf">
    <div class="upper-left-triangle"></div>
    <div class="upper-right-triangle"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="base"></div>
    <div class="front"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="shelf">
    <div class="upper-left-triangle"></div>
    <div class="upper-right-triangle"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="base"></div>
    <div class="front"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="shelf">
    <div class="upper-left-triangle"></div>
    <div class="upper-right-triangle"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="base"></div>
    <div class="front"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="shelf">
    <div class="upper-left-triangle"></div>
    <div class="upper-right-triangle"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="base"></div>
    <div class="front"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="shelf">
    <div class="upper-left-triangle"></div>
    <div class="upper-right-triangle"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="base"></div>
    <div class="front"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CODEPEN:

http://codepen.io/cogitatio/pen/dpword?editors=1100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because the shelves' height are percentages - relative to the overall height of the cabinet. The percentages of the current shelves add up to 100% and by adding more shelves the percentage goes over 100% and so you see the extra ones at the bottom.

I changed the height of the shelves to 14.5%

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXvOpV?editors=1100

```
.cabinet .shelf {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the `.cabinet .shelf` class height percentage based on the number of shelves being added in the cabinet.

With the looks from the code you shared, it is calculating the shelf height percentage with following formula

100% / Number of Shelves = each shelf height percentage
e.g.

100% / 5 = 20%

Now your adding 2 new shelves in the cabinet which makes the number of shelves to 7 so now the percentage to be set for each shelf is to be

100% / 7 = 14.30% approx.

(increase value after decimal point to adjust accurately. for me i added 0.15 more to make it 14.45% to adjust)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must set fixed height for *.cabinet .shelf* and increase height of *.cabinet*

```
.cabinet {
  position: absolute;
  width: 460px;
  height: 752px;
  background-color: #45221c;
  top: 40px;
  left: 30%;
  border: 10px solid #69342b;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cabinet .shelf {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 106px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/slaffko/pen/GjPJGL?editors=1100)